No Markdown rendering in VS Code Jupyter notebook on remote ec2
After upgrading my VS Code setup to 1.95.3, all my Jupyter notebooks on a remote ec2 instance stopped rendering Markdowns. The normal compute cells still work, but not a single bit of Markdown is rendered. Nothing I tried has work including:

Uninstalling and reinstalling Extensions

Removing VS Code installation and reinstalling


This makes using VS Code with Juypyter notebooks very difficult.

Finally noticed a configuration directory (.vscode-server ) on the ec2 (ubuntu) instance. I copied and renamed this directory structure, then restarted VS Code and the Markup rendering worked again in my Jupyter notebooks.
